# How to trigger Google Apps script function based on insert row via api

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

1. I have a Google Sheet with 5 columns (First Name, Address, SKU, Quote, Status).
2. I have an apps script function (createQuote) which looks at the above variable's values from google sheet row and create a google document quote replacing the variables to values.
3. I use Zapier to insert row into my above google sheet.

What am struggling with-:
I need a way to trigger my createQuote function right when a new row is inserted via zapier (Google Sheet API call).

I tried playing with triggers but couldn't make it, any help is appreciated.

thank you

here is the code for my function-

```
function quoteCreator(){

docTemplate = "googledocidgoeshere"
docName = "Proposal"

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Main")
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var full_name = values[1][0]

  var copyId   = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate).makeCopy(docName+" for "+full_name).getId()


  // Open the temporary document
 var copyDoc  = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document’s body section
 var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();
// Replace place holder keys/tags,  
 copyBody.replaceText("keyFullName", full_name);
 copyDoc.saveAndClose();
// Convert temporary document to PDF by using the getAs blob conversion
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

// put the link of created quote in the quote column
  var url = DocumentApp.openById(copyId).getUrl()
 var last = sheet.getRange(2, 7, 1, 1).setValue(url)


 }
```

Note-: I haven't put the loop yet in above, i'll do that once it starts working as per my requirements.

Comment: What's the code for your function?

Comment: @Brian - thank you, just updated the question with my function.

Answer (score 6):

Changes made via Sheets API or Apps Script do not fire onEdit triggers. I give two workarounds for this.

#### Web app

Have whatever process updates the sheet also send a GET or POST request to your script, [deployed as a web application](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app). As an example, a GET version might access `https://script.google.com/.../exec?run=quoteCreator`

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.run == "quoteCreator") {
    quoteCreator();
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Quote updated"); 
  }
  else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Unrecognized command");
  } 
}
```

The web application should be published in a way that makes it possible for your other process to do the above; usually this means "everyone, even anonymous". If security is an issue, adding a token parameter may help, e.g., the URL would have `&token=myToken` where myToken is a string that the webapp will check using `e.parameter.token`.

GET method is used for illustration here, you may find that POST makes  more sense for this operation.

Important: when execution is triggered by a GET or POST request, the methods `getActive...` are not available. You'll need to open any spreadsheets you need using their Id or URL (see `openById`, `openByUrl`).

#### Timed trigger

Have a function running on time intervals (say, every 5 minutes) that checks the number of rows in the sheet and fires `quoteCreator` if needed. The function `checkNewRows` stores the number of nonempty rows in Script Properties, so changes can be detected.

```
function checkNewRows() {
  var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var oldRows = sp.getProperty("rows") || 0; 
  var newRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main").getLastRow();
  if (newRows > oldRows) {
    sp.setProperty("rows", newRows);
    quoteCreator();
  } 
}
```

Comment: @GelaRam If this answer helped then you should at least up vote it.  You now have a new question, which should be asked in a separate post.  Include the code from both the POST request and the Apps Script code.